# How is setting the selectedindex of a select element different from selecting one item with a mouse?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-events, onchange

In a html page, if I use my mouse to select an item from a drop-down list(the select and option html elements), then the `onchange` event will be fired.
But if I use Javascript to change the `selectedindex` of a select element, then the `onchange` event won't be fired.

How are those two actions different?

How can I trigger the `onchange` event (not by calling `selectElement.onchange()` explicitly)?

Comment: Events for DOM elements are not fired when their values/attributes are manipulated in javascript. This is to prevent unintended code from being called when simply manipulating a value. Imagine that you have two fields, we'll say they represent percentages. If you update one field, the value of the other is automatically updated to the remainder of 100% based on the field you updated. If changing the value of the other field with javascript caused the change event to be fired, you would enter an infinite loop with each field updating the other endlessly.

Comment: So, the best practice, in cases where you want to repeat functionality in multiple places, is to refactor it into a separate method. You can then call that method `onchange` and also manually when changing a value.

Comment: Another example would be when you want to do automatic formatting of input (like currency). The user enters a value, `onchange` is fired, then you format the value and update the input's value with the formatted result. If doing so fired the `onchange` event, you would have a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this: http://jsfiddle.net/9xe9b/

```
$("#currency").change(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();

    $(this).val(formatCurrency(val));
});

$("#infinite").change(function(){
    var val = $(this).val();

    $(this).val(formatCurrency(val));
    $(this).change(); // simulate the change event. 
});

function formatCurrency(num) {
    num = isNaN(num) || num === '' || num === null ? 0.00 : num;
    return parseFloat(num).toFixed(2);
}
```

If you enter a value into the second textbox and pop open your console, you'll see this error:
`Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`

This is what we would have to worry about if changing a value in javascript caused a related event to fire. Infinite loops!

So, if you need to repeat functionality when changing a value through the UI or through javascript, you should create a function that does what you want and call it in the appropriate instances.